# Excel 2015 - Deleting rows that contain a specific string

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have got this huge .csv file that I need to work with (more than 1000000 rows). The problem is that it has got a lot of rows with data that I do not need. Is there a way I can get rid of these rows? Doing it manually is  near impossible.

Unfortunately, I am not familiar with VB. I know C++ and Fortran a bit though.

Thanks

Comment: So you need to delete a row containing a certain string? Is the string always in the same column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a job for Power Query (Excel 2010 and 2013), now called Get & Transform in the Data ribbon of Excel 2016.  For 2010 and 2013 you can download the free add-in from Microsoft. Create a new query that points to the CSV file. Then use the filter commands in the column headers to filter out rows that contain specific text strings. Save the query and load to the workbook. All done with a few mouse clicks, no coding experience required.

The best thing is that the query is repeatable. You can apply it to different CSV files, if required.